# Direct sum $\mathbb R^2$ and projection maps

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers, direct-sum

Really struggling with these types of questions and my past papers don't have answers, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $X = \{(x,0):x \in \mathbb R\}$ and $D= \{(x,x):x\in \mathbb R\}$

How would I prove that the direct sum of $X$ and $D$ are equal to $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Can you recite the definition of direct sum? And can you tell me the dimension of each of the subspaces you've listed?

Comment: R2 is said to be the direct sum of X and D so R2 = X ⊕ D, if R2 = X + D and X ∩ D = {0}. The dimensions are both 2 which is why I am confused?

Comment: Correct. Now, can you find a basis for $X$ and a basis for $D$, separately?

Comment: for X I have (1,0) and for D I have (1,0), (0,1)

Comment: I agree with $(1,0)$ for $X$, but are $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ in $D$?

Comment: would it be (1,1)?

Comment: Possibly, but you have to be the one to justify it. Supposing it was, is it true that $\Bbb R^2=X+D$ and $X\cap D=\{0\}$? I would try using your bases to answer this question, remembering that every element of a space is a linear combination of its basis.

Comment: ah (0,1)  would work

Answer (score 0):

We have $(x,y)=(x-y,0)+(y,y)$. Hence $\mathbb R^2=X+D$.

Its your turn to show that $ X \cap D=\{(0,0)\}$